# In Memoriam: Leonard Nimoy

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

It is my sad duty to inform the community that Leonard Nimoy has [beamed up for the last time](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/people/leonard-nimoy-dead-star-trek-spock-actor-dies-after-suffering-lung-disease-10076199.html). He will truly "Live long and prosper" in all our memories.

RIP

Comment: Oh starless night of boundless black.

Answer (score 31):

We are assembled here today to pay final respects to our honored dead. And yet it should be noted, in the midst of our sorrow, this death takes place in the shadow of new life, the sunrise of a new world; a world that our beloved comrade gave his life to protect and nourish. He did not feel this sacrifice a vain or empty one, and we will not debate his profound wisdom at these proceedings. Of my friend, I can only say this: Of all the souls I have encountered in my travels, his was the most.... human.

Comment: A fitting eulogy

Answer (score 23):

[image]

Answer (score 14):

RIP Spock.

Answer (score 10):

### *Dif-tor heh smusma ...*

[image]

<sub>*Live long and prosper* in Vulcan, according to the *New York Times*. If this is wrong, I'm sure some *Star Trek* expert will rip my head off ... er, I mean, will let me know.</sub>

Comment: [It appears to be](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Vulcan_language) from [the first movie](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Motion_Picture)

Answer (score 7):

William Shatner's tribute: the following image is a mosaic made up of pictures of Star Trek fans doing Vulcan salutes.

[image: mosaic]

Comment: This is truly incredible.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Comment: Video unavailable

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of an actor who death affected me more. I remembered him well from first-run episodes of Star Trek, the few times I was up late enough to watch and of course from watching countless reruns.

He was easily 50 percent of why ST was such a standout -- an alien (or half-alien) who had really depth of character, whose people and culture were thought out in exquisite detail. Spock was easily in the top ten of all television characters, perhaps top 100 or even higher of all characters in fiction -- there, I said it. And it is hard to imagine someone else in the role -- Nimoy was brilliant.