# Carrie Fisher has passed away

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

I'm very saddened to hear about the passing of Carrie Fisher,

> [she] drowned in moonlight, strangled by [her] own bra.

<sub>This is how she wanted it to be [reported](http://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2016/12/carrie-fisher-dies-strangled-by-bra-wishful-drinking)...</sub>

In all seriousness she was an inspirational figure both on and off the silver screen, best known as [Princess Leia](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/princess-leia), championing mental health as well as working as a script doctor and novelist.

She will be remembered.

Wherever you are, may the force be with you.

As an update, [Lucasfilms have stated](http://www.starwars.com/news/a-statement-regarding-new-rumors) they will not recreate Carrie Fisher digitally for future films.

Comment: On the plus side, principal filming for Star Wars 8 has been completed. It's possible that Carrie may ride again.

Comment: @Valorum at least they'll have time to to write it into Star Wars 9....

Comment: I'd be surprised if they hadn't totally killed her character off in the next film. Her role in VII was basically a cameo

Comment: She was inspirational in real life as well as on screen. I'm sure we are all sorry that she died, but is there a question here?

Comment: @Blackwood Meta on SFF is also a place where important, community-related events are discussed,  [including deaths of SFF icons in our time](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/6648/31178). Perhaps a new question about how we, as a community, utilize meta is worth the ask?

Comment: To the person who voted to close, [I find your lack of faith disturbing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zzs-OvfG8tE)....

Comment: It makes it even funnier, coming from a mod…

Comment: related meta discussion; [Should meta posts regarding the deaths of figures that are important to SFF:SE be on topic?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10444/should-meta-posts-regarding-the-deaths-of-figures-that-are-important-to-sffse-b)

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - you do realize the irony, right? Motti was 100% right about Vader - Vader's Force powers, indeed, were not enough to either retrieve the stolen plans (even when said plans were right in his grasp on Millenium Falcon), or gave him clarivoyance to find the Hidden Fortress...err Rebel base (it was found by attaching a technological non-Force tracker to Millenium Falcon).

Comment: @DVK-in-Florida it was an attempt at humour, please direct all discussion to the meta post Valorum linked.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - I know. I just can't let a Star Wars inaccuracy stand :) I commented on that post - the reasoning "for" is based on logical fallacy (popular!=ontopic). I don't feel strongly enough to post an actual answer arguing that.

Comment: Question reopened by Moderator: Since previous memorial posts of significant figures in the science fiction and fantasy arenas have been allowed, this one is allowed as well, reported as she asked it to be.

Comment: Did she write any science fiction or fantasy novels or scripts?

Comment: @user14111 she was a fantastic [script doctor](http://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/films/news/carrie-fisher-dead-star-wars-script-doctor-a7497951.html).

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - Good point but the link doesn't list any SFF works aside from *unconfirmed* prequel rumours. I'll refrain from commenting on  script quality of all the films listed out of general respect.

Comment: http://www.phoenixnewtimes.com/content/printView/6636095 - this interview says she punched up one of the prequels as well as rewrote some of her own dialogue in Jedi

Comment: She has a nice appearance in an episode of 30 Rock as a veteran screenwriter, and I enjoyed her roast of George Lucas: [“I hope I slept with you to get the job, because if not, who the hell was that guy?”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lZ97s396kb0&app=desktop)

Comment: Not sure where else to post this: http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/16238/is-there-any-legal-precedent-for-copyright-to-ones-image-when-digitally-recreat

Answer (score 18):

The post about [Leonard](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6648/in-memoriam-leonard-nimoy?noredirect=1&lq=1) has a bunch of pictures of him. Thought Carrie should get the same treatment.

**Guide the princess, the Force shall. In peace, rest, she may.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think any photoset of Carrie Fisher should be without this gem; http://inktank.fi/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Princess-Leia-behind-the-scenes-starwars17.jpg